# Get non-hashed urls when using Django's ManifestStaticFilesStorage

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

When using `ManifestStaticFilesStorage` the `static` template function always returns the 'hashed' file name (when `DEBUG=False`).  Is there any way to get the non-hashed regular file name in the template?  It seems odd that there's no obvious way since `collectstatic` always includes both hashed and non-hashed files, but the non-hashed ones would never be used.

I'm guessing what I need to do is create my own templatetag, but was wondering if I missed something.

EDIT to clarify what I want...

Right now `{% static 'css/style.css' %}` outputs something like `/static/css/style.a163843f12bc.css` while I'd prefer it to result in `/static/css/style.css` which should always be the latest version.

I suppose another solution is to use `{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style.css` by adding `'django.template.context_processors.static'` to the list of context processors.

Comment: Note that the `static` function returns the url to the static file (with hashed filename), not the hashed filename. I assume you want the url to the non-hashed file, not just the filename (which you already have otherwise you wouldn't be able to call `static`). Why not just remove the last path component and append the original filename? Out of curiosity, why would you want the non-hashed files in the first place?

Comment: @dirkgroten - does the edit help clarify?  Basically I'm rendering the template and the content is being cut-n-pasted so I want it to always point to the freshest copy.  The 'hashed' named file is essentially pinned to a particular version.

Comment: Ah ok. But you should then be careful on how you serve your static file: if your file server sets a 1yr expiry cache-control header, someone who’s downloaded the page will never see the new version of style.css. That’s the whole purpose of this Manifest: ensure browsers always load the latest version without having to worry about cache expiry.

Comment: @dirkgroten - right.. 99.9% of my content is intended to have a long expire and the users gets updated by pointing to a new filename.  However, in this one case I want to not point to the filename with the hash.

Comment: Then your solution using {{STATIC_URL}} works best.

Comment: The whole point of the hash is to always have the freshest version. If you never change the files then even after a new release, the hashes should not have changed (because they are calculated form the file contents like git hashes). If they have changed then the browsers are required to reload them - and that is exactly what you want. If you always use the same url (blank without hash) you can never really know whether the browser has the "freshest" version.

Comment: @Risadinha - It always gives the latest hash AT THE TIME IT"S RENDERED.  My use-case is that the URL is rendered and then used many months later when it may no longer be the latest.  The non-hashed URL always points to the most recent and the only issue with using it is caching (which isn't a concern in my use-case).

Comment: @Risadinha - scroll up to the comment starting "right.. 99.9%".  It's the right choice for most cases, but I have this one exceptional case.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use STATIC_URL but continue to use the `url` template tag, you could override `url()` in your custom subclass of  ManifestStaticFileStorage:

```
# add kwarg "clean"
def url(self, name, force=False, clean=False):
    if clean:
        return self._url(self.clean_name, name, force)
    return self._url(self.stored_name, name, force)
```

While `stored_name(name)` returns the hashed version `clean_name(name)` (same method signature) just replaces backslashes with slashes and returns the plain name.

This is untested but from the code in django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py it looks like this could work.

To activate your custom FileStorage class you need to point `settings.STATICFILES_STORAGE` to it.

In your templates, whereever you want to use the unhashed name, you'd write:

```
{% static 'css/style.css' clean=True %}
```

---

Some insights on how `static` works:

```
    @classmethod
    def handle_simple(cls, path):
        if apps.is_installed('django.contrib.staticfiles'):
            from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage
            return staticfiles_storage.url(path)
        else:
            return urljoin(PrefixNode.handle_simple("STATIC_URL"), quote(path))
```

So, this means that using `{{ STATIC_URL }}` is not far from what `{% static %}` without the staticfiles app does. The staticfiles storage class adds a layer of abstraction, checks for URL fragment and does URL quoting.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what I want is just concatenating the `STATIC_URL` with the relative file path.  However, the `static` template tag adds a little more functionality like proper escaping spaces and allowing assigning to template variables so I derived the following from the Django source and added it in an app as 'templatetags/simple_static.py':

```py
from django import template
from django.templatetags.static import PrefixNode
from django.utils.six.moves.urllib.parse import quote, urljoin

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def simple_static(path):
    """
    Simple concatenation of path with STATIC_URL

    Usage::

        {% simple_static path [as varname] %}

    Examples::

        {% simple_static "myapp/css/base.css" %}
        {% simple_static variable_with_path %}
        {% simple_static "myapp/css/base.css" as admin_base_css %}
        {% simple_static variable_with_path as varname %}
    """
    return urljoin(PrefixNode.handle_simple("STATIC_URL"), quote(path))
```

Then in the template I can do:

```
{% load simple_static %}{% simple_static 'css/style.css' %}
```

And it will output '/static/css/style.css' if `STATIC_URL` is '/static/'